# JSon Serialization Issue with Complex Object Type submmitted to MVC Controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, serialization

We would like some guidance on why a  List (below) of objects is not being populated when we call .getJson in jquery.

We have the following in c#.

```
public class NCListModel
{
   public NCListModel()
    {

    }
    public List<NCField> ActiveColumns { get; set; }
    public string IdColValue { get; set; }
    public string IdColText { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ListName { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public int RecordsPerPage { get; set; }
    public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    public string SortBy { get; set; }
    public string SortDir { get; set; }
    public string SearchBy { get; set; }
    public string SearchTerm { get; set; }
    public byte ViewMode { get; set; }
}

 [Serializable]
    [ProgId("NCField_NET.NCField")]
    public class NCField
    {
        public NCField();

        public bool CanShow { get; set; }
        public string Caption { get; set; }
        public short Col { get; set; }
        public short ColLen { get; set; }
        public short DataType { get; set; }
        public short FieldLength { get; set; }
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        public bool Hidden { get; set; }
        public string ImageName { get; set; }
        public bool IsDataField { get; }
        public bool IsDefaultFilter { get; set; }
        public bool IsFilter { get; set; }
        public bool IsID { get; set; }
        public bool IsLocation { get; set; }
        public bool IsSalesRep { get; set; }
        public bool IsSearchFilter { get; set; }
        public short LookupListID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ValueSQL { get; set; }
    }
```

in jQuery we assign a variable to the deserialized to get

```
var listinfo = {"ActiveColumns":[{"IsSalesRep":false,"IsLocation":false,"ValueSQL":null,"Name":"FullName","DataType":1,"Col":0,"FieldLength":0,"Caption":"Name","FieldName":"Customer.FullName","Hidden":false,"CanShow":true,"IsDataField":true,"IsFilter":true,"IsID":true,"IsDefaultFilter":false,"ColLen":0,"ImageName":"","IsSearchFilter":true,"LookupListID":0},{"IsSalesRep":false,"IsLocation":false,"ValueSQL":null,"Name":"CompanyName","DataType":1,"Col":2,"FieldLength":0,"Caption":"Company","FieldName":"Customer.CompanyName","Hidden":false,"CanShow":true,"IsDataField":true,"IsFilter":true,"IsID":false,"IsDefaultFilter":false,"ColLen":0,"ImageName":"","IsSearchFilter":true,"LookupListID":0},{"IsSalesRep":false,"IsLocation":false,"ValueSQL":null,"Name":"BillAddr2","DataType":1,"Col":6,"FieldLength":0,"Caption":"Bill Addr2","FieldName":"Customer.BillAddr2","Hidden":false,"CanShow":true,"IsDataField":true,"IsFilter":true,"IsID":false,"IsDefaultFilter":false,"ColLen":0,"ImageName":"","IsSearchFilter":true,"LookupListID":0},{"IsSalesRep":false,"IsLocation":false,"ValueSQL":null,"Name":"BillCity","DataType":1,"Col":7,"FieldLength":0,"Caption":"Bill City","FieldName":"Customer.BillCity","Hidden":false,"CanShow":true,"IsDataField":true,"IsFilter":true,"IsID":false,"IsDefaultFilter":false,"ColLen":0,"ImageName":"","IsSearchFilter":true,"LookupListID":0},{"IsSalesRep":false,"IsLocation":false,"ValueSQL":null,"Name":"BillZip","DataType":1,"Col":8,"FieldLength":0,"Caption":"Bill Zip","FieldName":"Customer.BillZip","Hidden":false,"CanShow":true,"IsDataField":true,"IsFilter":true,"IsID":false,"IsDefaultFilter":false,"ColLen":0,"ImageName":"","IsSearchFilter":true,"LookupListID":0},{"IsSalesRep":false,"IsLocation":false,"ValueSQL":null,"Name":"BillState","DataType":1,"Col":9,"FieldLength":0,"Caption":"Bill State","FieldName":"Customer.BillState","Hidden":false,"CanShow":true,"IsDataField":true,"IsFilter":true,"IsID":false,"IsDefaultFilter":false,"ColLen":0,"ImageName":"","IsSearchFilter":true,"LookupListID":0},{"IsSalesRep":false,"IsLocation":false,"ValueSQL":null,"Name":"NCCustomerID","DataType":3,"Col":99,"FieldLength":0,"Caption":"ID","FieldName":"Customer.NCCUstomerID","Hidden":false,"CanShow":false,"IsDataField":true,"IsFilter":false,"IsID":true,"IsDefaultFilter":false,"ColLen":0,"ImageName":"","IsSearchFilter":false,"LookupListID":0}],"IdColValue":"NCCustomerID","IdColText":"FullName","ID":120,"ListName":"Customer","HTML":null,"PageNumber":0,"RecordsPerPage":0,"TotalRecords":0,"TotalPages":0,"SortBy":"BillZip","SortDir":"asc","SearchBy":"FullName","SearchTerm":"","ViewMode":0}



we call this function in jquery.

function LoadData(st) {
    listinfo.SearchTerm = st;


    // need paging also.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: uLink,
        data: listinfo,
        async: false,
        success: function (json) {

            if (json.Message === undefined)
            { $('#table-body').html(json.HTML); }
            else {
                alert(json.Message);
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });

}
```

We see that listinfo is the complete object in jQuery.

The controller receives the object with the proper number of ActiveColumns BUT none of the properties for the individual NCField objects are populated.

```
public JsonResult LoadData(NCListModel data)

{.....}
```

Comment: The property names in your json are not correctly named to allow binding on post back - They would need to be `ActiveColumns[0].IsSalesRep: false, ActiveColumns[1].IsSalesRep: false` etc. But you could first try adding `tradition: true` to the ajax options.

Comment: the json string was created using the following code

Comment: public static string ToJSON<T>(this T obj)
       {
           JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
           return serializer.Serialize(obj);
      }